# the if condition of onResponse function not working properly

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to display some data from MySQL table after executing a query for a particular email address. But the `if` condition in the following code is not being executed :

```
public void onResponse(String response) {
    if(response.equals("true")) { 
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserProfile.class);
        intent.putExtra("email",EMAIL);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        alert.setMessage(response);
        alert.setCancelable(false);
        alert.setPositiveButton("OK1", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
        });
        alert.show();
    }
}
```

Why isn't it being executed?

Comment: What is the response that you got? Did you check that?

Comment: Use equalsIgnorecase that is response.equalsIgnoreCase("true") if you are returning a boolean as a String.

Comment: can you post your response here?